# Resolved Promises inside AngularJS Unit-Test not working with Jasmine spyOn

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, promise

I have problems with the following source code and the corresponding Unit-Test:

**Source:**

```
public laufeVorwaertsUndZurueck(laenge:number):ng.IPromise<any>{
 return this.ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.run(laenge)
    .then((response:any)=> {
        return this.ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.rotate(180);
    })
    .then((response:any)=> {
         return this.ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.run(laenge);
    })
    .then((response:any)=> {
        return this.ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.rotate(180);
    });
    console.log("done");
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
it("laufe 60cm vorwärts und laufe wieder zurück", () =>{
    var promise = qService.resolve("resolved");
    console.log(promise);
    spyOn(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService, "run").and.returnValue(promise);
    spyOn(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService, "rotate").and.returnValue(promise);

    baseBallAktionenService.laufeVorwaertsUndZurueck(60);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.run).toHaveBeenCalledWith(60);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.run).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.rotate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(180);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.rotate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})
```

Even tough I pass in a **resolved** promise object, the Callback-Functions inside the *.then* method are never called. The Source is fine when run normally, but behaves wrong when executed inside a Unit-test using jasmine's *spyOn*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use $digest after resolve the promise.**

*see below..*

```
it("laufe 60cm vorwärts und laufe wieder zurück", () =>{
    spyOn(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService, "run").and.returnValue(promise);
    spyOn(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService, "rotate").and.returnValue(promise);

    baseBallAktionenService.laufeVorwaertsUndZurueck(60);

    var promise = qService.resolve("resolved");
    $scope.$digest();

    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.run).toHaveBeenCalledWith(60);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.run).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.rotate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(180);
    expect(ev3DifferentialPilotAdapterService.rotate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you tell me why, please? Is there an alternative? We don't want to call $scope.$digest in all our test specs.